# How to call DHL tracking number lookup Service?

Tags: html, tracking, fedex, dhl

In my Magento code we have UPS hyperlink which has some parameters including tracking number when we click on that link it takes us to UPS site where we can the status for that passed tracking number. I want the same functionality for DHL tracking numbers too. Is there any way I can achieve it?

I found that for `FedEx`

```
https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber=[YOUR_CODE_HERE]
```

How to achieve the same for DHL service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope you find this useful.

Just change the [your_code_here] to your tracking number.

You can add &brand=DHL or &brand=Express if required, usually it auto populated.

[http://www.dhl-usa.com/content/us/en/express/tracking.shtml?AWB=[YOUR_CODE_HERE]](http://www.dhl-usa.com/content/us/en/express/tracking.shtml?AWB=)